# View which is outside the bounds of relativelayout is not accessible

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, accessibility

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="100dp"
            android:text="Hello World " />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

While using above layout in which button is outside is the parent relative layout bounds, button is not accessible (talkback doesn't read out the button details).
Can we make this button accessible?

Answer (score 0):

I used an [`AccessibilityService`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPmTA.png) that I wrote to analyse the "Node Debug Tree" that is made available to AccessibilityServices with your layout and got the following result:

```
     androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat@80007c5d;
        boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340);
        boundsInScreen: Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340);
        packageName: com.testapp.testproject;
        className: android.widget.FrameLayout;
        text: null;
        contentDescription: null;
        viewId: null;
        checkable: false;
        checked: false;
        focusable: false;
        focused: false;
        selected: false;
        clickable: false;
        longClickable: false;
        enabled: true;
        password: false;
        scrollable: false;
        [ACTION_SELECT, ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION, ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN]
```

At first I thought it might be the accessibility service, but then I looked at the LayoutInspector:

[image: Screenshot of layout inspector]

And it looks like it never gets rendered. So it looks like you can't hide a button like this.

I would also point you to [WCAG guideline 3.2.7](https://w3c.github.io/wcag/understanding/hidden-controls):

> People with low executive function, impaired memory, and other cognitive and learning disabilities may not be able to find controls needed to progress if they are hidden until focus is placed on them or a pointer hovers over them. They may also not remember where the control is the next time they interact with the site.
>
> Some design approaches hide controls needed to complete tasks and require certain user interactions, such as mouse-over, to display these controls. These required interactions can leave users with cognitive disabilities without a path forward.

So in general, this does not appear to be best practice on the surface